# How to order by select query according to month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a database table in which I am storing data in this format say May 2014. I want to fetch data from my table according to month i.e May 2014, Apr 2014, Mar 2014. . .Jan 2014
Please guide me what should be my select query? My column data type is varchar(450)
How should I use order by clause in my select query? Should I use Group By clause?

Comment: Fix the data type to be a date, say the first day of the month.  This will make using the table much easier.  You can format it to what you want on output.

Comment: Convert the string to date and use order by on the converted field

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok so should I use change my data type to date??
But I will be inserting the data as May 2014. I am not using any calendar control on my web form to store this date value, I am having a label control which will display current year and a dropdownlist which holds the month. I will insert data in this column after appending these two controls.

Comment: @Nisha Hello nisha, thanks for your suggestion, but please guide me with the select query.

Comment: ...I'm concerned you may just be dumping in the value via string concatenation, meaning you may be open to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes I will be doing that. So, what should be the right way according to you. Please guide me. My objective is to sort the data according to Month and Year, and Secondly I don't want to insert proper date.

Comment: You need to be using parameterized queries, but that's language/platform dependent.  There's questions/answers for most of the common ones here on SO, try looking them up.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

I think you can create a separate Look Up table (including all Months and Years) and join with your source table

Example:

**LookUp table**

```
DECLARE @LUDTTABLE TABLE 
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), [YEAR] VARCHAR(20),[MONTH] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @LUDTTABLE VALUES 
('2014','JAN'),
('2014','FEB'),
('2014','MAR'),
('2014','APR'),
('2014','MAY'),
('2014','JUN'),
('2014','JUL')
```

**Source table**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(900,1), DT VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('JAN 2014'),
('JUL 2014'),
('FEB 2014'),
('FEB 2014'),
('APR 2014'),
('JAN 2014'),
('JAN 2014')
```

**Result:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @TABLE A
JOIN    @LUDTTABLE B 
ON      LEFT(A.DT,3) = B.MONTH
    AND RIGHT(A.DT,4) = B.YEAR
ORDER BY B.ID
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Mr. Jithin, thanks for your suggestion. But I don't want to use any separate table for this. I want to store data as May 2014. and then use select query to fetch the data according to month. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A secondary table is actually a good way to deal with this issue, but you need to add one more column - how do you know to sort `'February'` _after_ `'January'`?  The db has no way to tell you mean the **month**, so would sort them alphabetically (which would put February first).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2008 cast your column to date format and order by month()

use the following snippet

```
 SELECT * FROM your_table_name  ORDER BY MONTH(CAST (your_column_name AS DATE))
```

For previous version use convert function to convert `varchar` to `datetime`

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY MONTH(CONVERT(datetime, your_column_name))
```

Comment: Except the OP doesn't have a complete date, so the cast/convert would fail.  And this also ignore indices, so the query will be slow on large tables.